# Migrating Magento 1.9.1.1 to Magento 2 using Migration Tool error

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I have been following the Magento2 developer documents http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-migrate-settings.html to migrate 1.9.1.1 database to new magento2.

I am running magento in APACHE, CENTOS, AWS. Now, having trouble moving forward to migrate settings and stuck here.

I am in the folder /bin and using the command below

```
php ./magento migrate:settings [-r|--reset] {/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.1.1/config.xml}
```

but getting errory everytime

```
-bash: --reset]: command not found



[Migration\Exception]



Invalid config filename: [-r



migrate:settings [-r|--reset] config
```

Please put me in right direction

Answer (score 4):

For Setting Migration No need to use`[-r|--reset]`, It throws an error.

If Setting will not migrate then it's automatically reset to default.

I always use

```
<code>php bin/magento migrate:settings D:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\data-migration-tool\etc\ce-to-ce\1.9.1.1\config.xml</code>
```

Answer (score 2):

I could run the settings command using the command below - removing the reset command and removing curly braces around config.xml path:

```
php ./magento migrate:settings /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.1.1/config.xml
```

Still not sure why it is not working with command [-r|--reset]

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `[-r|--reset]`. You use either `-r` or `--reset`. The square brackets indicate that what's inside is optional and the pipe is an "or" operator. So, you'll use:

```
php ./magento migrate:settings --reset /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.1.1/config.xml
```

Or:

```
php ./magento migrate:settings -r /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.1.1/config.xml
```